# Color como prop no funciona en typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind

les cuento que quiero traer el color de unos botones, creados con new-component y no funciona. Desde un principio, funcionó pero desdpués dejó de hacerlo.

```
interface ActionButtonProps extends React.ComponentProps<'button'> {
  color: 'primary' | 'secondary' ;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

function ActionButton({ color, children }: ActionButtonProps ) {
  const defaultStyles = `text-white bg-${color} w-full sm:w-auto sm:px-8 border-b-4 p-4 py-1 mt-6 text-lg border-b-black/25 rounded-full hover:border-b-transparent hover:translate-y-[4px] transition duration-150 shadow-lg shadow-${color}/25`
  
  return <button className={defaultStyles}> 
    {children}
  </button>;
}

export default ActionButton;
```

```
<div className='flex flex-col w-full justify-center sm:flex-row sm:gap-6'>
            <ActionButton color='primary'>Download for iOS</ActionButton>
            <ActionButton color='secondary'>Download for Mac</ActionButton>
          </div>
```